# Sending List<MultipartFile> from one service to other gives "Current Request is not a multipart request" exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, kotlin, multipart

- Taking in a list of multipart files and sending as a post request.
- Followed [Uploading a List of MultipartFile with Spring 4 restTemplate (Java Client & RestController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212557/uploading-a-list-of-multipartfile-with-spring-4-resttemplate-java-client-rest)
- Sending List from one service to other gives `Current Request is not a multipart request exception` message

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(values = ["/rest/send"])
class Controller {

@PostMapping
fun send(@RequestParam(value ="id") id: String, @RequestParam(value="files") files: List<MultipartFile): String {
val headers = HttpHeaders()
headers.contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

val reqBody = LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Any>()
reqBody.add("id",id)
for(file in files) {
val resource: ByteArrayResource = object ByteArrayResource(file.bytes) {
override fun getFileName():String() {
return ""
}
reqBody.add("files",resource)
}
val reqEntity =  HttpEntity(reqBody,headers)
val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
restTemplate.postForEntity<String>(url,reqEntity,String::class.java)
return "sent"
}
}
```